# Extending Addon and using its classes

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I have following case: 
I want to use an method in assistedservicestorefront from a custom made extension but it always fails at compiling as ant can't find the class that im looking for in assistedservicestorefront.

I thought that perhaps there is no way that an extension actually access an addon, so i created an custom addon specifically to access the addon i want.

It still fails.

Any Ideas?

I've tried:

I already defined it as required in extensioninfo.xml

Tried to create a custom addon.

Code:
This is my DummyAssistedServiceComponent

```
@Resource
private GkvUserService userService;

@Resource(name = "assistedServiceAgentAuthoritiesManager")
private DefaultAssistedServiceAgentAuthoritiesManager authoritiesManager;

public void refreshAuthorities() {
    String userId = userService.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    authoritiesManager.addCustomerAuthoritiesToAgent(userId);
}
```

**Error output:**

```
/opt/company/Project/hybris/bin/project/projectassistedserviceaddon/src/de/companysystems/project/assistedserviceaddon/controllers/DummyAssistedServiceComponent.java:5: 

error: package de.hybris.platform.assistedservicestorefront.security.impl does not exist
```

---

**EDIT :**

Ok, I've found my first error. I've put my class into the wrong folder.

I've put it into **\src** instead of **\acceleratoraddon\web\src**.

I moved the class and suddenly it compiled without a problem.

But there is still another problem:

I've created my custom addon because I wanted to access a method in another addon to use it in my custom extension. But it seems that it's not possible.

Hybris doesn't seem to allow to access addons from extensions. 
Only Addons are allowed to access them and overwrite them :(

Any Ideas? 
Otherwise, I'll have to take the method I wanted to use and write it again.

Comment: Have you also added assistedservicestorefront to  localextensions inside config folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a ride through [The AddOn Approach in Hybris](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b490bb4e85bc42a7aa09d513d0bcb18e/1905/en-US/8adc7ca3866910148ddfe860464f0fc4.html), that'll clear your doubts.

The AddOn concept aims at extending the Accelerator storefront without touching its core code base. To do so, the system automatically copies the folder & files to the target storefront extension during the build phase.

After the build phase finishes, the target extension(storefront) contains the following new folders:

- **web/addonsrc**, which contains the source code for each installed AddOn. This gets compiled automatically.
- **web/webroot/WEB-INF/addons**, which contains all the front-end components, such as images, JSP files, HTML files, and TAG files.

Which mean if you want to override/extend any existing addon functionality you have to create a custom addon and add a dependency to the existing addon which you want to override. So that system will load existing addon before your custom addon. Also, don't forget to install your custom addon to your storefront.

Comment: Is there a possibility to access Methods in an Addon from a Storefront? Creating a new Extension just for the sake of accessing one method seems a little bit excessive...